# TabControl.VerticalAlignment = Stretch doesn't do anything

Tags: wpf, layout, vertical-alignment, tabcontrol

I am trying to make a TabControl to auto resize according to the its outer space(it's in a StackPanel):

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="100">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TabControl 
                BorderBrush="Red" 
                BorderThickness="2" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">

                <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
                <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
            </TabControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The snippet above produces the following window, whilst I want the red border to reach the bottom of the window:

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is your `StackPanel`. StackPanels won't stretch their children.

Instead, use a `DockPanel`: The last child will be stretched to fill the remaining space (see [LastChildFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill.aspx), which defaults to `true`).

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="100">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <TabControl BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
                <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Explicitly setting `VerticalAlignment` is not necessary, since [its default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.verticalalignment.aspx) is already `Stretch`.

Related Link: [*Panels Overview* on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx)

Comment: I used your code, nothing; the TabControl's Vertical size is not docked as expected; I would think the problem is with the TabControl rather than the StackPanel.

Comment: Very strange... it works perfectly fine over here: I copy-and-paste the above code in a XAML window -> the red border stretches across the whole window. Could you try again?

Comment: Well your solution does work. Unfortunately based on the sircumstances of my windows that there are various parent it didn't work out. The solution to my particular problem was embedding it in a Grid setting the row's height to *.
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the height to parent window's actual height.

```
<TabControl 
    BorderBrush="Red" 
    BorderThickness="2"
    Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1"/>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2"/>
</TabControl>
```